# Style a DIV in the same way as a certain tag

Tags: html, css, tags

I have a DIV to which I want to apply a style currently prescribed for a certain tag (not class).
I want to use that as a base style for my container element, which will be used by its child elements that will use relative offsets for position and percentage for size.

Say, `<h2>` has `font-size:x-large; font-weight:bold;` by default. I could do:

```html
<h2>
  <div style="font-size: 50%;">something</div>
  <div style="font-size: 80%;">something else</div>
</h2>
```

But this is invalid HTML, because `div` cannot be inside `h2`.

So I need a way to say:

```html
<div style="whatever is currently applied to h2">
  ...
</div>
```

Is this possible without JavaScript (like sniffing out style properties using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you use `span`'s?

```
<h2>
  <span style="font-size: 50%;">something</span>
  <span style="font-size: 80%;">something else</span>
</h2>
```

And if you need them to be `display: block`:

```
h2 span {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HfQWz/

Although I would say you probably want to more specifically select the `span`'s with a class on the `h2`, wrapping `div.className`, or something.